# neo4j high cpu and open transactions

Tags: neo4j

is there a way to check why the server (neo4j dedicated) has high cpu after a while of running queries?

also is the attached monitor screen ok? lots of open transactions there, which only increase[image]

[image]

Comment: You can enable slow query logging and see which query takes so long. http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-settings.html#config_dbms.querylog.threshold You can also take a threaddump with kill -3 or jstack <pid>

Answer (score 1):

Opened should continue to increase. That is not how many are currently opened but rather just a total including transactions that were opened and are now finished and not running.

However, "current" shows 7 which means you still have 7 transactions running which probably explains the high CPU usage, depending on what those transactions are doing. Is it expected that you would have 7 transactions running? If so then there's probably nothing to worry about. If not, then you might want to look in to why those transactions didn't finish when you expected them to and you can also configure the execution card to limit the time each query can run for before being killed.

Comment: thanks. in that case i would expect to see the last TX Id same number as the opened transactions. that what confused me.
anything to do / check about the CPU?

Comment: Number of opened transactions/number of committed transactions are both reset every time you restart the instance. Last committed tx id is never reset, but from my understand, that value only increases on transactions that write data and not on read-only ones. So if you are doing a lot more reading that writing, then I think your numbers make sense.

As for CPU usage, I think it's hard to say without knowing what kind of processing you're doing, but I don't think anything looks out of line.

Comment: Is there any neo4j tool to profile the cpu activity when running queries?

Comment: Neo4j enterprise in 2.3.x has gotten metrics support with a ton of metrics that you can get into graphite and grafana, see: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/metrics-extension.html